# JS: Undo last OnClick evnet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I guess, that this is easy, but I can't figure it out.

I have a series of OnClick `buttons` (like a tree of choices).

Is there any easy way, how could I undo last click? I want this function to be fixed to only one button (in html). I know, that I can do this with series of many buttons, and in JS I can make them as OnClick, that will have opposite function, than I did in prewious step.

I hope, that I descriped it properly.

I also created a **Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/sz57cyyf/5/

When you click on button A, then will be buttons AA and AB shown. I want to go step back, so I can click on button BACK. What I want is a function linked to button BACK, that'll automatically do opposite function. And like this when you have buttons ABA, BAA etc. like in browser when you click "Back".

This is for users of my website. They will click on buttons and they will get to thing, that they want. So, you click for example like this: A -> AB -> ABA buttons (you have allways 2 choices). This works for me. But what I want is, that when you accidently click (4 example) on button AB, but you wanted to click on button AA, I want to go back a step. So You can get by pressing ".back" from AAA / AAB buttons to AA / AB buttons and then to A / B buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
$(".back").click(function () {
    if ($(".c").is(":visible")) {
        $(".c").css("display", "none");
        $(".b").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(".b").is(":visible")) {
        $(".b").css("display", "none");
        $(".a").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem with this is, that I have a "tree" of allways 2 buttons. So "Button A" -> "Button AB" -> "Button ABA" etc.. So every button has 2 more buttons where you can choice. It's pretty big code in this case. So I'm looking for something like "redo previous onclick" function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `data()` method to storing button value in html `data-*` attribute.

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
    var nextIndex = parseInt($(this).data("button")) + 1;
    $(this).data("button", nextIndex).text("Button-" + nextIndex); 
});

$(".back").click(function(){
    var prevIndex = parseInt($(".button").data("button")) - 1;
    if (prevIndex > 0)
        $(".button").data("button", prevIndex).text("Button-" + prevIndex); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-button="1">Button-1</button>
<button class="back">Back</button>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Seems working perfectly, but I'm probably little dumb. https://jsfiddle.net/sz57cyyf/3/ don't you please know, why is it not working in my example? (And my code in PC)

Comment: @HonzisNovák Because you don't added `data-button` attribute and you used `a b c` instead of `1 2 3`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sz57cyyf/5/ I've moved my project to JSF, it doesn't work for me, I'm doing something wrong :/ Coul you please edit my Fiddle, for button back to do that back function? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @HonzisNovák I can't understand what you do want. What you want to do?

Comment: This is for users of my website. They will click on buttons and they will get to thing, that they want. So, you click for example like this: A -> AB -> ABA buttons (you have allways 2 choices). This works for me. But what I want is, that when you accidently click (4 example) on button AB, but you wanted to click on button AA, I want to go back a step. So You can get by pressing ".back" from AAA / AAB buttons to AA / AB buttons and then to A / B buttons.